# Community Promotion Ads Twitter link

Tags: discussion, community-promotion-ads

The meta voting threads for community promotion ads 2013 are being rolled out now. All include the site's Twitter feed as a sample ad. And they do so using the depricated hashbang syntax which now merely redirects. It would be better to use the new standard Twitter URL form, without the hashbang.

Comment: ...and why can't you just edit them?

Comment: @Yannis. Well, I have done on Arquade and SciFi. Should I go round every single site in the network and edit them? Why not get them right in the first place?

Comment: Well, they are already posted, someone has to go round every single site in the network and edit them...

Comment: @Yannis. Well, in that case, perhaps this will server as a reminder so they get them right next time.